# Is it possible to add a dialog box which can change or open font for text?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, panel

I want to make a text button in my add-on panel. When I press on it, it needs to show a dialog box which I can change or open font in computer

Not only changing extrude, scale of text, like an [example of Darkfall](https://darkfallblender.blogspot.com/2020/03/the-text-tool-add-on-version-10.html), I want to add a choose font button in this dialog box.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! Yes, sounds possible. Can you please add more details eg. providing a mock-up of your panel or at least a detailed description of your idea? Consider that the bare minimum here is to show some effort towards your goal, also I'd recommend add the current state of your code to your question. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and I'd also suggest take the [tour] to learn about how this site works.

Comment: This has already been done with the blender text object when selecting a font. I would look into that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean at all. I just want to know how I made a dialog box including add font button

Comment: Why you close this question, I have type what I want to do. It's detail including already. I am beginner, I don't know how to do this

Comment: Clearly stated: "This question needs details or clarity." - Your question can be reopened anytime if it is clear enough, you show some effort or at least some research. *"I want it like this just with X"* is no reason to re-open it (IMHO). Suggest read the help pages. *Re your edit and if I get your idea*: Placing the button to load the font on that popup is a pretty bad idea since the button will open up the *File Browser* as usual and your popup will be gone when you are back. You'd have to re-call the popup which is too much for a beginner IMHO. Question is why you need this popup at all.